# In-App Purchase For $0.00

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Is it possible to set up an in-app purchase for $0.00?

Let's say you have a variety of non-consumable items that your users can download.  Some of them should cost money, and some should be free.  By putting all of these items as In-App Purchases, you can centralize their metadata and reduce the code for handling the downloads.

Would there be a problem with making an in-app purchase free?

Edit for Clarification:

My idea here is centralizing metadata. You have 10 items, 5 are free. You need to make a call via StoreKit to the App Store to retrieve the names, descriptions and prices of the 5 paid items--this is required per the docs. You also need to make a call to your own server to retrieve the same information for the 5 free ones, if these downloadable items are not in the App Store. Then you need to combine this information into one list of downloadable content.

By putting the free items into the App Store as $0.00 In-App purchases, you centralize the information about your downloadable content.

Is this desirable?  If it is, is it possible?

Comment: why would you even need to use the in-app purchase for the free items, couldn't you just skip it out all together and mimic as-if it were a purchase.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes App Store policies.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson Thanks, clarified my question.

Comment: @Matt Mc, I don't know how to set it up, but I have seen it done - as a matter of fact, some apps were doing it last week for the "5 Years of the App Store" celebration. One was an app called "Over" that allows a user to place text over a photo. They had several fonts and artwork packages available for free as in-app purchases. These items are normally charged in-app purchases, so there has to be a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it currently stands it appears that it is not available ([here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4009)):

> no free In-App Purchases are available

But Apple is going to implement this feature for developers with iOS7! ([source1](http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/27/new-for-app-developers-in-ios-7-text-to-speech-motion-effects-background-downloads-free-in-app-purchases-more/), [source2](http://news.softpedia.com/news/iOS-7-to-Offer-Free-Hosted-In-App-Purchases-364066.shtml))

I am sure that there are better documentation in the member center but I am currently locked out waiting for my boss to approve a new license agreement. This is a wonderful idea besides just the metadata reasons. It would allow the developer to offer free in-app purchases for special offers or periods of time too.

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you, that first link serves as an answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't allow you to set up in App purchases for $0. So there is no way of even thinking about this.

Regards

Rajeev

Comment: Have you got anything to back this up with. A link a google search anything because as it stands it is just a statement.

Comment: Hi Popeye,You can either shoot an email to Apple through your Apple dev a/c or resolution cetre. Else you can go through the App Store Review Guidelines "https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html"

Comment: @RajeevKumar, I think popeye was indicating that as an answer, this could do with padding out by backing it up with links to articles or documentation.

Comment: @JamesWebster Thanks that is exactly what I meant. That is why even though it was answer after `Rajeev Kumars` answer and they both basically say the same thing `Firo`s answer is much better because it has links and provides evidence.